# PHP - Not getting expected results with == comparison operator

Tags: php, comparison, string-comparison

With this code:

```
if($foo['bar'] == $baz) {
    $results[] = $foo;
}
```

I never reach the assignment `$results[] = $foo;` (with a certain value)

Now if I do (with this same, certain value):

```
strcmp(trim($foo['bar']), trim($baz));
```

I get a result of `0`, indicating the strings are in fact equal. So... why in the world can't I reach `$results[] = $foo;`?

Shouldn't $foo['bar'] == $baz be true if a strcmp of the two equals 0? What am I missing?

---

By the way, it's only one particular comparison that fails. Other comparisons using the same if statement will work fine.

example:

when $foo['bar'] == 'meat' and $baz == 'meat' I get $results['meat']

but when $foo['bar'] == 'meat sauce' and $baz == 'meat sauce' I get $results[]

Comment: Can you post the code surrounding this and possibly the real values being sent so it can be tested?  thnx.

Comment: @DeaconDesperado - Got it figured out. I simply included trim() in my test but not in the actual code that was having the trouble, sigh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The observed behavior does not make sense, so there has to be a hidden gotcha somewhere. Let's start with the fact that `trim` seems to make it work.

Did you use `var_dump` to verify that `$foo['bar']` and `$baz` really have the same value?

Comment: Thanks Jon. I had included trim() in my test but not in the code that was having the problem. When I saw the var_dump I saw that one result was one character longer, went "What the heck? I trimmed that re... uhm, oops". So thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you have tow arrays, say A and B and you want assing array B to A you do this:

```
$A = $B;
```

if you want assing just one element:

```
$A[] = $B[5]; // ether by index or key
```

in your case you was trying to assing whole array to an element from array, try this:

```
$results[] = $foo['bar'];
```

In case you want to assign whole array do like so:

```
$results['key1'] = $foo[];
```

Every key in results array will hold array.

Comment: Actually, I am trying to assign the whole array like that, not just one value. I am iterating through a multi-dimensional array and building a new array based on whether or not a specific value is present in each sub-array. It's part of a function to filter some returned results.